# TypeScript React onChanged: getting an error when trying to execute the web part in sharepoint

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sharepoint, web-parts

I don't understand why the `onChanged` attribute won't work, does it need a different parameter?

```
private _onScriptEditorTextChanged(text: string) {
    this.setState({ script: text });
}

public render(): React.ReactElement<IScriptEditorProps> {
    const viewMode = <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.state.script }}></span>;

    return (
        <div >
            <div className={styles.scriptEditor}>
                <div className={styles.container}>
                    <div className={`ms-Grid-row pzl-bgColor-themeDark ms-fontColor-white ${styles.row}`}>
                        <div className="ms-Grid-col ms-lg10 ms-xl8 ms-xlPush2 ms-lgPush1">
                            <span className="ms-font-xl ms-fontColor-white">{this.props.title}</span>
                            <p className="ms-font-l ms-fontColor-white"></p>
                            <DefaultButton description='Opens the snippet dialog' onClick={this._showDialog}>Edit snippet</DefaultButton>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <Dialog
                isOpen={this.state.showDialog}
                type={DialogType.normal}
                onDismiss={this._closeDialog}
                title='Embed'
                subText='Paste your script, markup or embed code below. Note that scripts will only run in view mode.'
                isBlocking={true}
                className={'ScriptPart'}
            >
                <TextField multiline rows={15} onChanged={this._onScriptEditorTextChanged} value={this.state.script} />
                <DialogFooter>
                    <PrimaryButton onClick={this._closeDialog}>Save</PrimaryButton>
                    <DefaultButton onClick={this._cancelDialog}>Cancel</DefaultButton>
                </DialogFooter>
                {viewMode}
            </Dialog>
        </div >);
}
```

}

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: Are you sure it's `onChanged` and not `onChange`. Which UI library are you using? What's the exact error?

Comment: The Error I'm getting is this one: Type '{ multiline: true; rows: number; onChanged: (text: string) => void; value: any; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ITextFieldProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Property 'onChanged' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ITextFieldProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.ts(2322)

Comment: I tried to change it to `onChange` but I just got even more Errors so i think it should be `onChanged`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at the documentation how to properly use the component, what props it accept...

i think it should be onChange, and u need to bind it, since u using "this" keyword inside onChange function:

```
<TextField multiline rows={15} onChanged={this._onScriptEditorTextChanged.bind(this)} value={this.state.script} />
```